# UICollectionView displays too few cells

Tags: xcode, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewController with an array of size 20 as the data source.

But when i run it, i see only 8 cells. NSLog's shows the count is still 20.

Is it not enough to have this?

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

{

```
return self.datasource.count;
```

}

Comment: What layout are you using for your collection view? Maybe it thinks it can only fit 8 on the screen

Answer (score 0):

What did you set in the following two delegate methods?

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    {
        return TotalItems / NoOfItemsPerSection;
    }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return NoOfItemsPerSection;
    }
```

Comment: numberOfSections has "return 1;" and numberOfItemsInSection has "return self.dataSourceArray.count"

Comment: Please check putting "numberOfItemsInSection" as 2. and "numberOfSectionsInCollectionView" as (self.datasource.count / 2)